# Why are the file formats different?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, file-format

When you go to a certain site to download an application. why can't you run the same file formats for different operating systems?

Comment: Because OS X and Linux does not support the Win32 library.  Linux does not support OS X's Coca framework

Comment: http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you **can** support the same file format on different operating systems provided that the format is an established one, such as JPG, PDF, MP3, ZIP, etc: all common operating systems have applications to display or play them.

Some operating systems have applications where a native format has been defined, such as DOC/DOCX for MS Word or ODT for Open/Libre Office, but most equivalent applications will have an import/export function to allow reading and writing of non-native formats.

The executable file formats, which contain machine code and system library calls, such as EXE and DLL for Windows, cannot from their nature work on a different OS with different system calls or machine instructions, though for instance the Linux Wine project allows some Windows executables to run in Linux, provided the hardware uses the same instruction set.

Some formats, such as AVI for video, may be supported on different operating systems, but that does not guarantee that any given file can be transported from one OS to another: it depends whether the ancillary CODECs have been implemented on the target OS.

Strangely, one of the simplest formats is plain text, yet this often causes incompatibilities, because of the different native new-line characters (LF, CR+LF or sometimes CR); yet the same TXT file extension is used in different operating systems. In particular, one of the common uses of text files is scripting, sequences of operating system commands interspersed with tests and controls: these are very different between different operating systems, though since OSX is built on Linux, some compatible scripts are possible; furthermore there are several Windows implementations of Linux shells which also allow some degree of compatibility.

In summary, most file formats are not handled directly by an operating system, but by applications running above it. So, with the exceptions noted above, there is generally nothing in an OS to exclude a particular file format: all that is required is an appropriate application to support it.